# Unit gunicorn.socket could not be found

Tags: django

I get a 502 Bad Request error after deployment with nginx.

I am using a digitalocean droplet.

Everything works fine locally, so I must have missed something while bringing over the files to filezilla...?

sudo journalctl -u gunicorn>

No journal files were found.

sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2019/07/29 13:42:25 [crit] 1666#1666: *2 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 138.68.234.34, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 13:42:30 [crit] 1666#1666: *4 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 13:42:30 [crit] 1666#1666: *6 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/favicon.ico", host: "myi.pad.dress", referrer: "http://myi.pad.dress/"
2019/07/29 13:50:00 [error] 1666#1666: *8 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 13:55:50 [crit] 1666#1666: *10 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 13:57:18 [crit] 1666#1666: *12 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:02:23 [crit] 1666#1666: *14 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:02:51 [error] 1666#1666: *16 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:09:55 [crit] 1666#1666: *18 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:09:59 [crit] 1666#1666: *20 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/favicon.ico", host: "myi.pad.dress", referrer: "http://myi.pad.dress/"
2019/07/29 14:15:18 [crit] 1666#1666: *22 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:19:58 [crit] 1666#1666: *24 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
2019/07/29 14:21:00 [crit] 1666#1666: *26 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.114.6.201, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "myi.pad.dress"
```

---

sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket

```
Unit gunicorn.socket could not be found.
```

---

pip freeze

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
cryptography==2.1.4
Django==1.11.11
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
enum34==1.1.6
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.12
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
ipaddress==1.0.17
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
netifaces==0.10.4
psycopg2==2.7.4
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.26.1
PyICU==1.9.8
pytz==2018.3
pyxdg==0.25
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
virtualenv==15.1.0
```

---

/home/django/django_project# nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/django

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

---

settings.py

```
import os
import netifaces

def ip_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
        addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
        for x in (netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6):
            if x in addrs:
                ip_list.append(addrs[x][0]['addr'])
    return ip_list

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'abc'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myipaddress']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'users',
    'blog',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Show your gunicorn.service, please! Because I understand what a mistake is that the gunicorn socket is not being activated as due.

Comment: @EndersonMenezes
What do you mean with service? What file do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sudo journalctl -u gunicorn>
>
> No journal files were found

If your gunicorn.service files are not configured, the service is probably not running. You need to set up a service for gunicorn for the server to start, and nginx has a socket to read. I use the tutorial below for my OS, you can see something compatible for yours, most all steps are similar and have the same purpose.

[Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)